# iOS/Swift - How to verify a user's email with Firebase WITHOUT using it for auth?

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

(Swift/SwiftUI - iOS) My app allows authentication via firebase auth with phone number. Users can optionally add their email address in the preferences page of the app (to receive marketing emails, not for authentication).

Does anyone know if I can use firebase a cloud function to verify these user emails but NOT use them for auth? I can already save the user email to firestore, I just want to know if there is a way for firebase to email the user to confirm the email, then e.g. write a verified boolean value to firebase.

I know I can verify emails with firebase auth but these users did not sign up with email and have no password. I also don't want to overwrite their phone number as primary signin method for firebase auth as I am not supporting login with username/password.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `emailVerified` property through the Admin SDK, which is indeed what you'd use in Cloud Functions. If you look at the documentation on [updating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user), you'll find this sample of how to do this:

```
getAuth()
  .updateUser(uid, {
    email: 'modifiedUser@example.com',
    phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
    emailVerified: true, // 
    password: 'newPassword',
    displayName: 'Jane Doe',
    photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled: true,
  })
```

Comment: Thank you but I believe this is for updating the user's email in firebase auth, I am trying to verify their email without modifying their user details in firebase auth as all of the users logged in with phone. On https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user it does say that the admin SDK can "Verify emails without having to go through the out-of-band action flows for verifying emails." but there is no documentation regarding this feature